# Generate table indexes using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to generate table indexes along with the rest of the database schema with Fluent NHibernate?  I would like to be able to generate the complete database DDL via an automated build process.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In more recent versions of Fluent NHibernate, you can call the `Index()` method to do this rather than using `SetAttribute` (which no longer exists):

```cs
Map(x => x.Prop1).Index("idx__Prop1");
```

Comment: Correct, the API has changed and this is now considered the correct way to set indexes.  I've updated the answer on this question to reflect this change.  Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Do you mean indexes on columns?

You can do it manually in your `ClassMap<...>` files by appending `.SetAttribute("index", "nameOfMyIndex")`, e.g. like so:

```
Map(c => c.FirstName).SetAttribute("index", "idx__firstname");
```

or you can do it by using the attribute features of the automapper - e.g. like so:

After having created your persistence model:

```
{
    var model = new AutoPersistenceModel
    {
        (...)
    }

    model.Conventions.ForAttribute<IndexedAttribute>(ApplyIndex);
}


void ApplyIndex(IndexedAttribute attr, IProperty info)
{
    info.SetAttribute("index", "idx__" + info.Property.Name");
}
```

and then do this to your entities:

```
[Indexed]
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I like the latter. Is is a good compromise between not being non-instrusive to your domain model, yet still being very effective and clear on what is happening.

Answer (score 10):

Mookid's answer is great and helped me a lot, but meanwhile the ever evolving Fluent NHibernate API has changed.

So, the right way to write mookid sample now is the following:

```
//...
model.ConventionDiscovery.Setup(s =>
            {
                s.Add<IndexedPropertyConvention>();
                //other conventions to add...
            });
```

where IndexedPropertyConvention is the following:

```
public class IndexedPropertyConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<IndexedAttribute>  
{
    protected override void Apply(IndexedAttribute attribute, IProperty target)
    {
         target.SetAttribute("index", "idx__" + target.Property.Name);
    }
}
```

The [Indexed] attribute works the same way now.