# Fluent NHibernate index creation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

Can you help me write this SQL code to fluent nhibernate

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_OKS_Plan_7_1205579333__K6_1_2_3] ON [dbo].[OKS_Plan] 
(
   [Position_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [UID],
[Description],
[FileName]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607935/generate-table-indexes-using-fluent-nhibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for auto mapping:

```
.Override<Entity>(mapping => mapping.Map(entity => entity.Property).Index("IDX_Property"))
```