# How to rebuild index using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following code. To improve performance, i am looking forward to rebuild the index on the table before I start scanning for the first 500 items in the table.

```
    using(var session = sManager.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var rows = 0;
            foreach (var idsChunk in total.Chunk(500))
            {
              .... <Execute Update>
            }

            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Can you please suggest if it is possible for me to rebuild the indexes on the table using NHibernate and if so then how?

Regards.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607935/generate-table-indexes-using-fluent-nhibernate

Comment: he's not asking to have the index create at schema creation time,  He wants NHibernate to rebuild an already existing index.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This isn't the purview of what NHibernate does.  NHibernate is an ORM, not a database management tool.